# phpQuery selectDocument right way ?

Tags: select, switch-statement, document, multiple-instances, phpquery

please, help me!...

**What is the right way to switch between documents with phpquery ?**

```
/* fetch section html */
$secdoc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html, 'utf-8');

/* ................ */
/* .. some actions. */
/* ................ */

while (cur < max)
{
    $soldoc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html, 'utf-8');
    phpQuery::selectDocument($soldoc);

    /* ................ */
    /* .. some actions. */
    /* ................ */

    phpQuery::selectDocument($secdoc);
}
```